# How to check if variable is a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use validation for the variable 'name' to make sure that the user is typing in words.

**My ineffective solution:**

```
name = input("What is your name").lower()
if name[0] == "a" or "b" or "c" or "d" or "e" #etc..:
    print("Success")
else:
    print("You must type in letters!")
```

Comment: Your other issue is that you need to use `==` to test for equality; `=` is for assignment

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? Because `input` has completely different semantics, and the question can be interpreted in different ways...

Comment: It is Python 3.

Comment: Please don't tag as 2.7 in future if your issue is in 3.x because we rely on those tags to determine which version you are using.

Comment: roganjosh oh ok

Comment: name[0].isalpha() - is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for [`str.isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha), which returns true iff all the characters in a string are alphabetic.

(As an aside, to find out whether an object is a string is done with `isinstance(x, str)`.)

```
>>> 'x'.isalpha()
True
>>> '6'.isalpha()
False
>>> '-'.isalpha()
False
>>> 'hello'.isalpha()
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `str.isalpha()`

Replace str with the user input. Returns true if entered value is a string otherwise false.